# Confusion about MKOverlayView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit, mkoverlay

I've been working with layers for MapKit on the iPhone, and one library that I came across was this one: https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo/.  It's very helpful, and seems to work fine.  However, I'm trying to go through and understand a bit how it works, but I'm having some trouble.

On this page, for example: https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo/blob/master/MapLayerDemo/Classes/CustomOverlayView.m,
at the top, there are 4 custom functions defined.  I assume these functions are adding on to the normal features of MKOverlayView?  The thing is, I can't find where any of these new functions are actually **called from**, and thus I'm having some trouble understanding how this page works.  It doesn't seem to be from any of the other files within the project.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: having looked through the project, they aren't called from anywhere that i can see, perhaps would be worth putting a few log statements in to see if they are called at all?
it could just be that they are useful functions that have been left in for your convenience, however aren't necessary for the project to run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  They are indeed called from the project, but for the life of me I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some extended discussion with you in comments:

The override-able functions of MKOverlayView, such as `canDrawMapRect` cannot easily be traced back to their calling code because that code is obfuscated somewhere in the MapKit.framework.

Instead, the typical approach is to re-read their documentation until you get a mental picture of what the framework is using the function for. (There is such a thing as decompiling binaries, although that is generally frowned upon and I do not recommend it.)

`canDrawMapRect` documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009715-CH1-SW10

After reading their documentation, I inferred this: Somewhere in the MapKit.framework, `canDrawMapRect` is being called prior to actually drawing the view.  If you didn't override that function in your subclass, it calls the super-class's default implementation, which always returns YES and then calls `drawMapRect:` (Which MUST be overridden if you are subclassing MKOverlayView, or else nothing will draw!)

The class you linked above potentially returns NO. In that particular case, it appears the code in MapKit.framework skips calling `drawMapRect:` and nothing is displayed (or refreshed).

**So, long story short:** for this case, you have to play code-detective and hope the documentation is written clearly enough to figure it out without being able to see all of the code.

Edit: Just to further clarify - It appears MKOverlayView must be subclassed to actually generate something visible.

---

My original answer before getting to your underlying question --

> Short answer: Those are private functions for use within that class.
>
> Long answer: Functions declared in an empty-name category at the top
>   of implementation files are visible only to the class the category is
>   extending.  Thus, those functions can only be called within that
>   class's implementation. (C++ equivalent would just be declaring the
>   functions private)
>
> 3 of those 4 functions are called within that same .m file.  Without
>   digging around, I'm guessing they wrote the first function and then
>   later decided to not use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Well they are defined in the .m file, but from where in the project are they actually called?

Comment: Yeah, but these are just all just definitions for functions... doesn't there first one have to be actually called somewhere, not just defined?

Comment: Yes, but that's within another function that isn't called anywhere.  In other words, where is canDrawMapRect, which calls zoomLevelForZoomScale, called?

Comment: I believe those are called internally from within the framework in response to display redraw events and the like.  CustomOverlayView's  canDrawMapRect is overriding the functionality of MKOverlayView.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html for more info on what overriding those functions does.

Comment: Thanks -- I've read that page already, and it doesn't seem like MKOverlayView.h even has these functions to begin with, so that is what's confusing me.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting confused somewhere between how overriding functions in subclasses of existing Cocoa classes works and how views in Cocoa can dictate their own drawing behavior. I'm not sure I can clarify this any better through StackOverflow's comment system. I'm sorry!

Comment: Hmm... so is it possible to see exactly where that first function is called, or is that hidden to us as developers?

Comment: Ahh, I finally understand your question! Deleted some of my confused comments, posting reply in my answer.